# Is it possible to import docx on python3 cgi scripts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi, docx, python-docx

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi, os
import docx     #-->>importing docx throws internal error on apache2 server while accessing the script as shown in sys log error below
print("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("<html><body><h1>Online Form</h1>")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
print("<p>Upload your file: <input type = 'file' name = 'filename' /></p>")
print("<input type='submit' value='Submit' />")
print("</form></body></html>")
#User uploads draft document here
fileitem = form['filename']
if fileitem.filename:
   fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
   open( '/home/'+fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
   message = 'The file "' + fn + '" was uploaded successfully'
else:
   message = 'No file was uploaded'
```

apache2 error logs shows that there is no docx module

> [Sun Oct 28 02:20:42.040073 2018] [cgid:error] [pid 19404:tid 139701431580416] [client 10.254.101.169:51915] End of script output before headers: stack.py
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/var/www/stack.py", line 3, in
>
> import docx
>
> ImportError: No module named 'docx'

But below output shows docx module gets imported successfully in python3 command line

```
host@ubuntu:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docx
>>>
>>>
```

Comment: The script will run as a different user from your normal login when under Apache - check your Apache config files and `/etc/passwd` for something like `_wwwdata` or similar. That user may have a different `PYTHONPATH` setting. Or you may have installed `docx` module in your $HOME somewhere and the Apache user may be looking in his/her $HOME rather than yours.

Comment: When running from command line, try importing `docx` then `print(docx.__file__)` to see where the module is. Then make sure the Apache user's PYTHONPATH includes the containing directory.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. As you rightly said, Apache server runs as www-data. I installed docx for all users and it worked fine

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project and remember to come back if you get stuck - questions, and answers, are free ;-)